# What is ILookup for and why doesn't it extend IFn?

Tags: clojure

Maps seem to be both, and we can do both

```
({:a 1} :a)
```

(Because it is an IFn) and

```
(:a {:a 1})
```

Because it is an ILookup. Additionally, RT/getFrom allows strings and arrays to be looked up by index and Java Maps by key and IPersistentSets by member in a similar fashion

What does ILookup give you, other than the ability to use keywords on it? Why is this better than IFn?

In particular, `datomic.EntityMap` seems to be an ILookup but not an IFn.

Comment: at least part of your premise is flawed - `(instance? clojure.lang.ILookup #{})` => `false` `(:a #{:a})` => `:a`

Comment: @noisesmith that's a set, not a map

Comment: "(:a {:a 1}) Because it is an ILookup"

Comment: that is to say, the assumption that `(:a x)` works because `x` is `ILookup` is false.

Comment: So looking at RT/getFrom, there are some other things that can be looked up by symbol, like Java maps and IPersistentSets.

Comment: Also, a more nitpicky point where this question is concerned, `:a` is not a symbol, it's a keyword, Clojure has both and they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Right, because keywords reference themselves, whereas symbols reference something else. You can tell it is a keyword because it starts with a colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clojure.lang.ILookup` is for things in which keys (of arbitrary type, not necessarily keywords) can be looked up. `clojure.lang.IFn` is for things which can be called as functions. Based on these mission statements alone, it's not clear that there's any intrinsic link between them.

Moreover, things that are both `ILookup` and `IFn` don't always implement `valAt` and `invoke` in the same way:

```
(.valAt [0 1 2] 123)
;= nil

([0 1 2] 123)
;; throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

The reason for the above behaviour is that `invoke` works like binary `nth` on vectors, whereas `valAt`'s purpose is to implement the semantics of `get`.

(Opinions may be divided on the subject of what `invoke` on vectors *should* do, but that's a separate discussion.)

None of this means that `ILookup` is "better" than `IFn` – it's just a separate interface with a separate purpose. Introducing an `extends` relationship between them would need to happen for a reason, and I'm not sure there's much to be gained by doing that at this time.

Comment: Where is there documentation on `ILookup`? I've found [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ILookup.java), but so far nothing on the intended semantics.